# Error :the namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'AboutDialog1'

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am a newbie to WPF. 
I am practising the sample code in WPF unleashed .
When I was trying to implement the Attached events , I modified the class name an Xaml file to a different class name , that is as same as my namespace of  the new page and I am debugger 
complains with this error:

> Error 1   The namespace '' already contains a definition for 'AboutDialog1'

Can anybody please let me know why am I getting such errors?

my code :

```
<Page 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      x:Class="AboutDialog1" ListBox.SelectionChanged ="ListBox_selectionchanged"

    Title="attachedevents">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Foreground="White">wp4 unleashed </Label>
        <ListBox> 
            <ListBoxItem>chapter 1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>chapter 2</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

```
namespace AboutDialog1
{
    public partial class AboutDialog: Page
    {
        public AboutDialog()
        {

        }
        void ListBox_selectionchanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
                MessageBox.Show("you have selected " + e.AddedItems[0]);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`x:Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752309.aspx) should point to a class, not the namespace containing it, so it should be `x:Class="AboutDialog1.AboutDialog"`

Comment: Thank you :) I tried it . and so I was trying to use the namespace in the place of the class .well thanks for many me understd